# How would you free this malloc'd array?

Tags: c

This is part of my pebble code. I am just wondering what the best way to free it is?

```
    case CGM_BGSX_KEY:;
  //APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "SYNC TUPLE: BGS X AXIS");
  strncpy(last_bgsx, new_tuple->value->cstring, BG_MSGSTR_SIZE);
  if (strcmp(last_bgsx, " ") == 0) {
    // init code; initialize the array
    bgsx_array = (int*)malloc(MAX_BG_ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(int));
    for (uint8_t n = 0; n < MAX_BG_ARRAY_SIZE; n += 1) {
      bgsx_array[n] = 0;
    }
  }
```

Would you just do

`free(bgsx_array);` ?

Comment: Yes - Did you try it before posing the question?

Comment: Yes - what is your concern? What do you think the alternative are? When are you planning  on freeing it?

Comment: I freed it that way but it made no difference in the heap I still had allocated at the end. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong.

Comment: Huh? Did you check with a memory error checker such as `valgrind` (or similar on windows?)

Comment: I am trying to run Valgrind on my mac. I get this 48 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 238 of 342
==80741==    at 0x1000A2EA1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)

Comment: Is the the only memory you `malloc`? Are you sure it called your `free` line? How did you view the heap? Try @DavidC.Rankin suggestion to use a tool

Comment: Well, if it truly made no difference to the heap allocation, then either you repeated the same allocation somewhere else, or your memory-manager is borken.  I would go with 'you measured it wrong'

Comment: The heap allocation is what the cloud pebble app is telling me is still allocated. I moved the location of the free() and it did help. I appreciate all your help. I will keep working at it!

Comment: `strncpy` is being used incorrectly in this code. You forget to null-terminate the buffer before calling `strcmp`.

Comment: You can use `calloc` instead of the initialization loop